# Settings view iOS app whose variables can be used in other view controllers

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS programming and am creating an app with several viewControllers. One of the viewControllers is a settings tab and I'd like to store a few variables so that I can use it across the controllers. Is there a standard way of doing this? I'm currently looking into `NSUserDefaults` but any design patterns out there would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't simply want to pass information - i also want to store it.

Comment: CoreData is also an option and I personally think its a must know especially if you find yourself needing to store structured data. Plus, it's a very elegant solution to data storage and handling once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

**1. With Storyboards -**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"xyzView"]) 
    {
        MyViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.objectPassedFromPrevViewController = dataToBePassedToNextViewController
    }
}
```

**2. With Navigation Controller -**

```
DestinationViewController *destinationController = [[DestinationViewController alloc] init];
destinationController.objectPassedFromPrevViewController = dataToBePassedToNextViewController;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:YES];
```

**3. While Adding Subview -**

```
DestinationViewController *destinationController = [[DestinationViewController alloc] init];
destinationController.objectPassedFromPrevViewController = dataToBePassedToNextViewController;
[self.view addSubview:destinationController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inclination to use `NSUserDefaults` is a good one. Its made for storing and retrieving user settings and preferences for your app.